# Как сделать так, чтобы бот ждал сообщения от человека?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Как сделать так, чтобы бот ждал сообщения от человека а потом зависимо от ответа чтото снова ниписал в чат?

Мне нужно чтобы когда человек написал  "Ok ping" бот ответил, а потом ждал ответа человека, и например если человек напишет привет то бот отправит в чат привет
Нужно чтобы получилось примерно так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIqXl.jpg

```
from discord.ext import commands
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["Ok ", "ok "])

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Hello {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

Comment: Когда я вставил это в код и запустил, у меня выдало ошибку 
NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Comment: Я уже всё сам пофиксил, и оно работает. Спасибо