# Как подождать ответа пользователя?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Делаю мультисетап для своего бота. Нужно сделать так, что бы он задавал вопрос (просто отправляя сообщения, вот так: `await ctx.channel.send('Какой будет мой префикс?')`). И ожидал 30 секунд, а потом забирал ответ себе в переменную.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать так, чтобы бот ждал сообщения от человека?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339008/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, сначала создадим функцию `check`:

```
def check(m):
    return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
```

Теперь зададим ваш вопрос:

```
await ctx.channel.send('Какой будет мой префикс?')
```

Теперь делаем ввод:

```
answer1 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30) # 30 сек. ожидания
```

Узнаем ответ:

```
answer1 = answer1.content
```

Отправим ответ:

```
await ctx.channel.send(answer1) # префикс
```

Comment: Может хватит заниматься накрутокой?

Comment: @RAINGM хорошо, больше так не буду.